# What is ととと in this sentence?

Tags: translation

```
うわ！　ととと……
```

Is it something like "oh oh oh"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole phrase just means "***oops***", "***uh-oh***", "***sorry***", etc.

It is the emphatic (and/or comical depending on the context) version of the common exclamation 「おっと」, which is the "dictionary" form.

If you are interested in pronunciation, 「おっと」 and 「夫{おっと} ("husband")」 are pronounced differently.

「おっと{HLL}」: "Uh-oh"

「おっと{LHH}」: "husband"